# Accessing an ArrayList from a subclass

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to access an ArrayList from a subclass so that I can total the values of each card in a game. In order to total the values though, I need to access this ArrayList without creating a new method.

This is the parent class in progress:

```
public class Bridge
{
    //instance variables
    private final String[] SUIT_STRINGS = {"Clubs","Diamonds","Hearts","Spades"};
    private final String SUIT_CHARS = ("CDHS");
    public final int SUIT_AMOUNT = 4; //there are 4 different suits

private Suit[] hand;

////////////////////////////////////////////

public Bridge(String handToProcess)
{
    this.hand = new Suit[SUIT_AMOUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < SUIT_AMOUNT; i++) //creates the suit classes in the corresponding index
    {
        this.hand[i] = new Suit(SUIT_STRINGS[i]);
    }


    String token;
    int index;


    try
    {
        Scanner textScanner = new Scanner(handToProcess);
        textScanner.useDelimiter(" ");

        while(textScanner.hasNext())
        {
            token = textScanner.next(); //token takes is one of the hands in the line of hands

            index = SUIT_CHARS.indexOf(token.charAt(1)); //set index to the location of the matching suit char
            this.hand[index].addCard(token.charAt(0)); //takes the value of the card and adds it to the hand


        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}

public void printHand()
{
    System.out.print("Analyzing hand: ");

    String unprocessedCards;
    for (int suitNum = 0; suitNum < SUIT_AMOUNT; suitNum++)
    {
        unprocessedCards = this.hand[suitNum].printSuit();
    }


}

public void printTotalPoints()
{
    int totalPoints = 0;

    for (int suitNum = 0; suitNum < SUIT_AMOUNT; suitNum++)
    {
        totalPoints += this.hand[suitNum].suitPoints();
    }


}
```

}

This is the subclass:

```
public class Suit
```

{

```
private ArrayList<Card> cards;
private String suitStr;

private final int MIN_LONG = 5;
private final int VOID_POINTS = 3;
private final int SINGLETON_POINTS = 2;
private final int DOUBLETON_POINTS = 1;

//////////////////////////////////////////

public Suit(String theSuits)
{
    //final int POSITION_OF_SUIT = 1;
    /*switch(theSuits.charAt(POSITION_OF_SUIT))
    {
        case'C': this.suitStr = "Clubs";
        break;
        case'D': this.suitStr = "Diamonds";
        break;
        case'H': this.suitStr = "Hearts";
        break;
        case'S': this.suitStr = "Spades";
        break;
    }*/
    this.suitStr = theSuits;
    this.cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
}

public void addCard(char face)
{
    if (face >= '2' && face <= '9')
    {
        CardWithNumber cardToAdd = new CardWithNumber(face);
        this.cards.add(cardToAdd);
    }
    else
    {
        CardWithFigure cardToAdd = new CardWithFigure(face);
        this.cards.add(cardToAdd);
    }

}

public void printSuit()
{
    //System.out.print(this.suitStr + "\t"); //formatting; may remove later
    for (Card currentCard: this.cards)
    {
        System.out.print(currentCard + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

}

public int suitPoints()
{
    int suitPoints = 0;

    //check to see if there are more than 5 cards
    if (this.cards.size() > MIN_LONG)
    {
        suitPoints += this.cards.size() - MIN_LONG; //for every card over 5 of a suit you get one point
    }
    else if (this.cards.size() == 2) //if there are 2 cards
    {
        suitPoints += DOUBLETON_POINTS;
    }
    else if (this.cards.size() == 1) //if there is 1 card
    {
        suitPoints += SINGLETON_POINTS;
    }
    else if (this.cards.size() == 0) //if there are no cards
    {
        suitPoints += VOID_POINTS;
    }


    return suitPoints;
}
```

}

I don't see a way to access the ArrayList cards without creating an accessor method of some kind (which is not allowed in this particular assignment).

[UML Diagram of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOT8J.png)

> Class Descriptions
>
> BridgeClient has the main method that: •  creates Scanner object that
>   will allow reading from the hands.txt file •  for each line in the file
>   o creates a Bridge object (by calling the appropriate constructor)
>   o calls printHand method o    calls printTotalPoints method
>
> Card is an abstract class that represents a single card in the given
>   hand. It contains:  • one instant variable: o face of the card : 2,3,
>   …, 9,T,J,Q,K,A •  toString and accessor method •  abstract method
>   getPoints that when implemented by the subclass calculates the value
>   of the card
>
> CardWithFigure extends the Card and contains implementation of
>   getPoints method for card objects with faces: T, J, Q, K, or A. It
>   defines final String MAPPING that is set to “TJQKA”. It uses this
>   string to calculate points. Notice that the number of points
>   corresponds to the position of the appropriate letter in the MAPPING
>   string:       Aces   count as 4  = 14 - 10        Kings  count as 3  = 13 - 10
>         Queens count as 2  = 12 – 10
>                  Jacks  count as 1  = 11 – 10
>                  Tens   count as 0  = 10 - 10
>
> CardWithNumber extends the Card and contains implementation of
>   getPoints method for card objects with faces: 2,3,…, or 9
>
> Suit class implements set of cards in a suit. It contains:  • two
>   instant variables: o  cards – ArrayList of Card objects in one suit
>   that the hand contains o  suitStr – the name of the suit this object
>   represents: Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts or Spades •   constructor that
>   instantiates cards with the default ArrayList constructor, and sets
>   the suitStr to the given value •  addCard method – creates an
>   appropriate Card object and adds it to the cards list •   printSuit
>   method – displays all the cards in the suit • suitPoints method –
>   calculates the card points in the suit
>
> Bridge class contains: •  several instance variables: o   hand – array of
>   Suit objects for the given hand o SUIT_STRINGS – array of names of
>   suits o   SUIT_CHARS – a String containing first letters of each suit:
>   “CDHS” that can be used for mapping of the input suit value to the
>   name of the suit. For example, if the input is 2D – the index of ‘D’
>   in the SUIT_CHARS gives us index of “Diamonds” in the SUIT_STRINGS
>   array •   several methods: o  Bridge (the constructor)   instantiates
>   the instance variable hand   takes the input line and fills the hand
>   with appropriate data o   printHand method -  prints all four suits
>   (please see the sample run, it is possible that some suits are not
>   present)  o   printTotalPoints method - calculates total points for the
>   given hand

Comment: But `Suits` is not a subclass of anything here (except `java.lang.Object`, of course).

Comment: You can't use private variable from outside of the class.

Comment: Technicalities aside, I don't understand your design: why does Suit(e) need to know about a list of cards? To me Suite is more like an enum, and a list of cards contains Card objects, each of which belongs to one Suite.

Comment: (Ah, so it is spelled Suit.) I would rather make Suit an enum or something like that, and each card then has a reference to one Suit. IMO Suit is not a collection of cards, it's a property of them.

Answer (score 0):

To access any field from the subclass, declare it as protected (not private)

Comment: See my question about design. This indeed solves the visibility issue, but still the design is weird. How is a card suite a special case of the game of Bridge, for example?

Comment: Your design is actually weird. Maybe you have to do a complete redesign, or there is any misconception of java and inheritance. Maybe it's easier that you explain exactly what you want to do, and maybe people can help you with the design.

Comment: I added the uml diagram of the project as well as the descriptions of the classes I needed to implement